# need help creating a scaling list method in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a method called scaleByK that should replace every integer of value k with k copies of itself. For example, if the list is: [2, 4, -2, 5, 3, 0, 7] before the method is invoked, it should be [2,  2,  4,  4,  4,  4,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  3,  3,  3,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7 ] after the method executes. Note that the method should remove from the list all 0s and negative values.

this is what I have so far

```
public void scaleByK(){
      for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        if(list[i]<0||list[i]==0){
          for(int j=i+1;j<length;j++){
            list[j-1]=list[j];
          }
          length-=1;
        }
        else{
          for(int k=i;k<list[k]-1+i;k++){
            for(int x=length-1; x>k;x--){
              list[x+list[k]-1]=list[x];
            }
            for(int g=k+1; g<list[k+i];g++){
              list[g]=list[k];
            }
          }
          i=list[i]-1+i;
          length+=list[i]-1;
        }
      }
    }
```

length=7 when the method starts

When I run the method this is what I get
2  2  4  -2  -2  5  3  0  0  7

The original list is 2  4  -2  5  3  0  7

here is my print method

```
public void print() { 
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
            System.out.print(list[i] + "  "); 
        System.out.println(); 
    }
```

The length resets back to 7 every time I run the program.

Comment: First of all use an structure that can be resized (the easiest way an implementation of `java.util.List<Integer>`.

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting your values in this array, so it won't work. You might want to create a second array of the size of the sum of integers and fill it then.

Try applying your `print()` method on each step of iteration to vizualize your algorithm and sort the problems out.

Answer (score 0):

I've got 2 versions here for you, first using [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and then just with arrays:

```
public void scaleBy(int[] ints) {

    ArrayList<Integer> newInts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String myList = "";

    for (Integer integer : ints) {

        if (integer > 0) {

            for (int i = integer; i > 0; i--) {
                newInts.add(integer);
                myList += integer+", ";
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("[ "+myList.substring(0, myList.length() - 2)+" ]");
}

public void scaleByArray(int[] ints) {

    int[][] arrays = new int[10][];
    int length = 0;
    int arrayCount = 0;
    String myList = "";

    for (int integer : ints) {

        if (integer > 0) {
            length += integer;
            int[] temp = new int[integer];

            Arrays.fill(temp, integer);

            arrays[arrayCount] = temp;
            arrayCount++;
        }
    }


    int[] master = new int[length];
    int position = 0;

    for (int[] array : arrays) {
        if (array == null)
            break;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            master[position] = array[i];
            position++;
            myList += array[i]+", ";
        }
    }

    System.out.println("[ "+myList.substring(0, myList.length() - 2)+" ]");
}
```

Both versions output the same thing but obviously the first method is preferable, please comment below if you need anything.

Also worth a quick mention, `List<>` structures cannot hold primitive types like `int` or `double` or `bool`, instead they have to be wrapped by classes such as `Integer`, fortunately as you can see this doesn't have a big impact on what we're doing here.

Answer (score 0):

Just with printing:

```
public static void scaleByK(int in[]){
        for(int a = 0; a < in.length; a++){
            if(in[a] > 0){
                for(int b = 0; b < in[a]; b++){
                    System.out.println(in[a]);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Replacing the array:

```
public static int[] scaleByK(int in[]){
        int length = 0;
        for(int a = 0; a < in.length; a++){
            if(in[a] > 0){
                length = length + in[a];
            }
        }
        int temp[] = new int[length];
        int count = 0;
        for(int b = 0; b < in.length; b++){
            if(in[b] > 0){
                for(int c = 0; c < in[b]; c++){
                    temp[count] = in[b];
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        in = new int[temp.length];
        for(int d = 0; d < temp.length; d++){
            in[d] = temp[d];
        }
        return in;
    }
```